# .ipynb files can we protect with password and save on cloud?

Tags: python, passwords, cloud, jupyter

Is it possible to save jupyter files on clouds with file level password ?
so that it will be double safe with cloud password as well as file password!

right now I am using only google drive to store my file.

Is there a better way to save the file with protection ?